# CSS style stop working?

Tags: java, css, servlets

I'm working on a web application using Java code, I had changed my code by making each page start from a servlet class.

Java code in servlet "indexServlet":

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        DataGathering dBConnector = new DataGathering();
        List<Long> lstDetailVewOID;
        lstDetailVewOID = dBConnector.getDetailVewOID();
        request.setAttribute("detailVewLst", lstDetailVewOID);
        // pass the list to jsp page.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Since then the CSS code stopped working, and it gives me this error :

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost:8080/firstApplication/Style-Sheet/Template-Style.css".

When tracing the code, I found that by running the `doGet()` method inside the `servlet` class, it's call the page and run it, then get back to the servlet again to close the method, I guess the error because of this procedure but am not sure and I can't solve it.

When searching through the internet i figured that the type should be text/css but i already did that, and the same CSS file was working find before changing the code.

calling the CSS file inside the jsp page:

```
<link href="Style-Sheet/Template-Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Edit:
web.xml mapping:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.Teklabz.Servlets.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of the web.xml which defined the servlet? I'm interested in the URL pattern for the servlet. It seems to me that the CSS request is invoking the servlet (which it shouldn't) but need to see the web.xml to be sure

Comment: @NickJ i just added the web.xml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm think you return static resources like css and images through your servlet. This is bad itself, but if you do, you need set right mime type in response headers. Actually i'm think you should change servlet-to-url mapping from /* to somewhat like /*.jsp, so, all other static resources will be handled by your tomcat/jetty, they do it right.

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern> <!-- right here! -->
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I used to work on c#, this is my first project using java. i don't know what did you meant by saying "return static resources through your servlet". also you said it's bad practice, then what is the right thing to do. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss it's all right, this is very usual newbies error. When you map ALL browser request to your servlet, you MUST handle them ALL, even simple out requested file like css, js, or image file. Usually it's not what you actually want (except you really want read and out static content i.e. from DB). So you may map browser request only on request you want to handle (i.e. *.jsp) and let pass requests for static content to default tomcat servlet. This  servlet can out simple static resources well-formed (with proper mime type).

Comment: thanks, it's working now, but i have a question if you didn't mind, i set the application to start from a specific servlet. and as you see in the question, the url in web.xml is empty (even if it's not doesn't matter), when i start the application the url contain the name of the servlet ".java", but if i go to the servlet from the code direct, or typing it in the browser directly the url will appear as it was written in the web.xml. it's give the same result but with the right url. how can make it start with the right url from the beginning. thanks

Comment: I'm not completely understand your question, but i'm can see you mix all your java knowledge in one dish. So i'm recommend read some basics, sorry